# Natvis visualizer to view member pointer type as array

Tags: arrays, pointers, visual-studio-2015, natvis

In the Visual Studio 2015 watch window, pointers can be watched as array by adding a comma and the array length, e.g. d,10 will display 10 elements for a double * d.

Is it possible to create a Natvis Type Entry which does this based on the number of indirections, ie. for d, d* and d** in a different way?
Usually those are even members of a type, e.g. struct s { double* d }, but i want to avoid having to write custom visualizers for all those types.

The question is tagged for VS2015 but solutions for vs2017 or vs2019 are welcome if there are any.

**Edit1:**
Here's a simple example of what i'm looking for:

```
struct S
{
    double* v3;  
    double** m3;
};
int main()
{
    double* pv3 = new double[3]{ -1,-2,-3 };
    double** ppm3 = new double*[3]{ new double[3]{ 1,2,3 }, new double[3]{ 4,5,6 }, new double[3]{ 7,8,9 } };

    S s;
    s.v3 = pv3;
    s.m3 = ppm3;

    double v3[3] = { -1,-2,-3 };
    double m33[3][3] = { { 1,2,3 }, { 4,5,6 }, { 7,8,9 } };
}
```

- pv3 and s.v3 should be visualized like v3 and
- ppm3 and s.m3 should be visualized like m33

I know that treating **every** double pointer as a double[3] might not be what everyone would want but in certain codebases like the one i'm working on this is the 99% usecase.

[image: ugly annotated vc watch window snapshot]

Comment: Can you please give a short and simple code snippet for which you want a visualizer (so giving the variables, their types and how you want it to be displayed)!?

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry, but it looks like you can't achieve easily what you want to.

When adding `<Type Name="double*">` or `<Type Name="double**">` to Natvis Visual Studio complains

> Natvis: NatvisFile.natvis(xx,x): Error:  not allowed for primitive type 'double**'

So without a code change you would need to add natvis for all of your relevant structs.

But looking at your codebase I want to point you to the [CppCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines), especially to these rules:

- [I.13: Do not pass an array as a single pointer](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i13-do-not-pass-an-array-as-a-single-pointer)
- [R.14: Avoid [] parameters, prefer span](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r14-avoid--parameters-prefer-span)
- [R.11: Avoid calling new and delete explicitly](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly)

If your codebase would follow these rules and not do array-to-pointer decay, then the full type info would be available in the debugger.

Another approach might be to encapsulate `double` in a strong type. Please compare [this blog post](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/) on Fluent{C++}. But this might only work easily if you do not have a legacy API requiring `double*` or `double**`.

Comment: This is all good advice and i'm working on it, but as you said on the last line, it's indeed a large, 30+ year old codebase and needs time to adapt to the new world. I was just hoping that MS maybe is aware of such struggles since it seems to be a common case in old codebases, and provides some backdoor, even if it would be difficult to be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed in your example, you have a structure `S`, so you can create `natvis` for this type:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="S">
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="v3">v3, [3]nag</Item>
      <CustomListItems>
        <Variable Name="i" InitialValue="0"/>
        <Loop>
          <Item Name="m3[{i}]">m3[i],[3]nag</Item>
          <Exec>++i</Exec>
          <If Condition="i&gt;=3">
            <Break/>
          </If> 
        </Loop>
      </CustomListItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Result for your example:
[image: result]

But, as @Werner Henze already answered, you can't create `natvis` for `double`

Comment: `loop` does not work in `vscode`. Any workaround for that?

Comment: Are you sure?  I worked with VS Code a bit, I checked `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.9.8-win32-x64\debugAdapters\vsdbg\bin\Visualizers\ATLMFC.natvis` - this file contains Loop as well.

Comment: I have tried in Linux system and failed. If you have time can you kindly take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359355/extend-display-range-of-arrayitems-indexlistitems-using-natvis?noredirect=1#comment127858705_72359355).  As one of the approaches, I have tried here `loop` but failed. Some other approaches were also unsuccessful. Would be great if you kindly go through my question.

Comment: I guess, you use `gdb/lldb` for debugging ("type": "cppdbg"). So, in [this case](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis)

>  a subset of the Natvis framework has been ported to the Visual Studio Code C/C++ extension and the code resides in the MIEngine shared component.

As WardenGnaw  [wrote](https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine/issues/1095#issuecomment-764961245)
> I believe MIEngine does not support `Loop`.

Comment: Yes, and for that purpose I could not use `loop` in my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359355/extend-display-range-of-arrayitems-indexlistitems-using-natvis) too. Asked in different platform about the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359355/extend-display-range-of-arrayitems-indexlistitems-using-natvis), unfortunately no response came yet. Also I have seen Documentation, provided `natvis` file (seen in windows OS in vscode installation directory) but my approach are seems to be correct.

Comment: @touraille, a link to your question would be appropriate